# Reappearing folder on the desktop

Tags: windows-7

I have a folder on the desktop that **I created** a while ago and it is empty. Everytime I delete it reappears after restart (hibernate/power on again, etc..)

How do I get rid of it?

Comment: What's it called? It might be associated with some kind of synchronizing program that needs that folder to be able to sync.

Comment: It is called "Silvia" and I created it with pictures of my GF.

Comment: Are the pictures coming back too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I searched through registry for the folder name out of desperation. And It came up in the Toshiba Bluetooth Stack registry. The key was named "Inbox". So I guess I transfered some files via bluetooth to this folder and it was automatically set up as inbox. After changing the key to different I solved this.

Answer (score 1):

It would be best to figure out what process is creating it.  Start up stuff can be examined by running MSconfig.  This may give you some clues as to why it is happening.  You might also lock down your desktop folder with security settings and see if something throws an error when it can't create that folder.

You can lock down the folder by right clicking the folder and then going to the security tab.  You probably want to hit the Advanced button so that you can make the folder NOT inherit from its parent.  Examine who the owner of the folder is and take ownership of it.  You could then remove all permissions from the folder. (As owner you can give yourself back permissions after you are done.)  You could potentially just remove permissions to add files to the folder.   From the advanced menu you could also add auditing to the folder and view the auditing information in the event viewer.  ( http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310399 ) .

Comment: how do I lock it down?

Comment: added some more info on that.